# Magento base url not reflecting value changed in database (missing /)

Tags: magento, url

This is one of those things that on the surface of it seems very simple to resolve, but it's got me beat!

I can see from searching around that quite a few people have had this issue crop up but there seems to be no solution that I can find.

What I've done:
1. Transfered my site from the root folder into a /shop folder.
2. Changed the database entries for secure/unsecure base urls to https://www.dnabaits.com/shop/
3. Cleared out all the Cache and Tmp files.
What's happening:
The whole site is functional but no styles or scripts are being loaded because the paths in the head are missing the trailing / after shop. 
So instead of getting this
mydomain.com/shop/skin/........
I'm getting mydomain.com/shopskin/........

An example Url from my page source

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.dnabaits.com/shopskin/frontend/default/dna/css/lightbox.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: If you're sure you cleared all cache. Indeed it's very strange...

Comment: Definitely cleared the cache. In the end I just deleted the entire cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file make sure you have this (with trailing slash):

```
 RewriteBase /shop/
```

Another possibility is that your Store Configuration Scope for your Store View has a different setting.  Change your Configuration Scope in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web` and make sure your URL settings aren't customized there.

Comment: Looking at it. This is where the problem is. The admin isn't working properly though, it's not loading that style/javascript either so when I go to edit to secure/unsecure url's I can't save them. It has to be something to do with this though as I can see the trailing / is missing under 'Main Website' & 'Default Store View' is there any way to edit this without using the admin?

Comment: Yes you can edit that in the `core_config_data` table.  Here is a great article on doing that: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data

Comment: Yeah I've already use phpMyAdmin to change the secure & unsecure URL's to https://www.dnabaits.com/shop/ which it shows up in magento admin, but when I changed the scope I could see that the final / was missing but it wouldn't let me change it.

Comment: You can use phpMyAdmin to change the URLs again to add that trailing slash.